# Inserting in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

def convertToBinaryData(filename):
    #Convert digital data to binary format
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        blobData = file.read()
    return blobData

def insertBLOB(empId, name, photo):
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Connected to SQLite")
        sqlite_insert_blob_query = """ INSERT INTO new_employee
                                  (id, name, photo) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"""
        empPhoto = convertToBinaryData(photo)
        
        # Convert data into tuple format
        data_tuple = (empId, name, empPhoto)
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("File inserted successfully as a BLOB into a table")
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert blob data into sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("the sqlite connection is closed")
            
            # 1. Opera 

insertBLOB(2, r"emkit", r"C:\Users\CASH OFFICE 3\Desktop\EEK.zip")
```

The above code gives the following error:

```
Connected to SQLite
the sqlite connection is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\KP\Newpy\blb_ins.py", line 35, in <module>
insertBLOB(2, r"emkit", r"C:\Users\CASH OFFICE 3\Desktop\EEK.zip")
File "E:\KP\Newpy\blb_ins.py", line 21, in insertBLOB
cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
MemoryError
```

I have already 1 record inserted. This is the second record I want to insert.

Comment: just see wat is the size of the binary object ?

Comment: The .zip file is 564MB